# python regex removing the duplicates inside the parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

I have a successful code, which adds the words to the parenthesis: but i need to remove the duplicates in it.

My code:

```
import re
import collections

class Group:
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []
        self.text = []

with open('text1.txt') as f:
    groups = collections.defaultdict(Group)
    group_pattern = re.compile(r'^(\S+)\((.*)\)$')
    current_group = None

    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        m = group_pattern.match(line)
        if m:    # this is a group definition line
            group_name, group_members = m.groups()
            groups[group_name].members.extend(group_members.split(','))
            current_group = group_name
        else:
            if (current_group is not None) and (len(line) > 0):
                groups[current_group].text.append(line)

for group_name, group in groups.items():
    print "%s(%s)" % (group_name, ','.join(group.members))
    print '\n'.join(group.text)
    print
```

My text file:

```
 Car(skoda,benz,bmw,audi)
 The above mentioned cars are sedan type and gives long rides efficient
 ......

Car(Rangerover,Hummer,audi)
SUV cars are used for family time and spacious.
```

Outputs as:

```
Car(skoda,benz,bmw,audi,Rangerover,Hummer,audi,ferrari,lamborghini,porsche)
The above mentioned cars are sedan type and gives long rides efficient
......
SUV cars are used for family time and spacious.
```

Here **audi** is the **duplicate** in the output,How can i remove the duplicates inside the parenthesis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use regex to remove duplicates: Make `members` in `Group` a `set` (i.e. `self.members = set()` instead of `self.members = []`). Duplicates are then automatically removed. However, you will not be able to use `groups[group_name].members.extend(group_members.split(','))`. Instead, you must union sets using the `|` operator or update them with `update`:

```
groups[group_name].members |= set(group_members.split(','))
```

or

```
groups[group_name].members.update(group_members.split(','))
```

Alternatively, you could just call `set` before outputting to do the duplicate removal there:

```
print "%s(%s)" % (group_name, ','.join(set(group.members)))
```

**Beware that a `set` is not ordered, so if you need your ordering to remain the same as in the input, this will not work. Instead, you will need to manually filter the list for duplicates:**

```
filtered_members = []
for x in groups[group_name].members:
    if x not in filtered_members:
        filtered_members.append(x)
```

Comment: why would you union, why not just add? Also the ordering will be different using sets

Comment: At least for me, `set(['a', 'b']) + set(['b', 'c'])` gives `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'set'`. Union is the closest thing `set`s have. There is also `update`, which I will add to the post momentarily.